# Tab function is not working Properly if we have editable text in the table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a table with scrollable bar in X & Y direction having fixed table header. More over, i have given text boxes randomly in both Table Header and  Table rows. On pressing the tab Key, only the header part is moving and the body remains static and vice verse. I need to move the entire table(both **header** and **rows**) when we enter tab function.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Once check, Did you give the scrolling to entire table or to a particular TR...

Comment: I have given scrolling to entire table. I have included some text boxes in the header also. you can have a reference from this site  http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Answer (score 0):

To answer you, I think you should first separate the table into two and give the illusion that they are stuck with CSS, then remove the scrollbars of the header, and then create your module JavaScript. It would create a module that listens and interprets `table.onscroll` movements to move simultaneously the header and table values.

I have no module to offer you for your problem. Sorry. I hope you will succeed in creating this module!

Comment: I dont have much idea on that. Even am not able to find like that same codes in forum. Thanks for responding